# NextJS - build fails even though dev runs fine, complaining about React Hooks where I'm not using them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

first-time poster here. I'm pretty new to React & JS in general, and I've been working in NextJS. Interestingly, my project runs just fine when I run `next dev`, but fails when I use `next build`.

I get the following error:

```
Error: React Hook "useFunction" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

What's interesting about `useFunction` is that it is *not* a Hook - I define it as a function in the same file as a component `FunctionButton` like so and use it as part of the `onClick` event handler

```
const useFunction = async () => {

  const result = await someStuff();
  return result

}


const FunctionButton = () => {
  return <Button onClick={() => useFunction()}>Click Me</Button>;
};

export default FunctionButton;
```

Any idea why this isn't building successfully? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it thinks `useFunction` is a hook is because that's how React's linting checks work. They rely on the use prefix to determine that it's a hook:

> We provide an ESLint plugin that enforces rules of Hooks to avoid bugs. **It assumes that any function starting with ”use” and a capital letter right after it is a Hook.**

So, merely because your function starts with `use`, React takes it to be a hook. A solution would be to rename your function or add an `eslint-ignore` comment.

Comment: wow, thank you! that did the trick. much obliged

Comment: Glad to help. Just make sure to mark my answer as accepted if you feel it helped

Answer (score 1):

React considers the files whose name starts with the word `use` as hooks even though they aren't.

There are to ways to solve the issue:

1. simply rename your file. *(does not start with `use`)*
2. add `/* eslint-disable */` block comment at the top of the file.